# Guessing a functional form to use for fitting an exponentially decaying spectrum with peaks

Tags: data-analysis

I'm trying to fit an experimental spectrum (Intensity vs frequency) in which the intensity exponentially decays as frequency increases. However, there are peaks amidst the exponentially decaying background.

To fit this spectrum, what type of function could I use to account for these peaks?

So far I tried multiplying the exponential decay by gaussians that peak at the location of the experimental peaks. It looks like I can't carefully show multiple peaks using this method, they simply blur together into one broad peak superimposed on the exponentially decaying background.

Maybe I just haven't found the right coefficients to use in my functions to make the expression look qualitatively similar to my data.

Thanks for any advice or ideas!

*edit*
to clarify, I haven't actually started fitting my data yet. I've just been messing around in Mathematica with test functions.

Also, I'm not really sure if this is a good forum to ask for such a problem, but I thought math people might have some insight and/or be curious about the topic.
Are there other stack exchange forums that are more suited for my question?